# WP. Functions integration into child theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a child theme. The CSS I integrated into my child theme and it works perfectly. But now I want to make some amendments in my themes functionality. I copy from my parent theme, for example, `product-tab.php` to an exact direction in my child theme, modify the file, save, but after refresh no changes in my page. If I do it in the parent theme it works. I think that I should integrate that `product-tab.php` into my functions.php file (I mean that information first get from my child theme directory not from parent theme by default), but I don't know how because I'm a newbie in PHP coding.
Can anybody give one example how to integrate any PHP file from parent theme to a child theme. Can anybody write an example of a code using the information below?

parent theme direction:

`/public_html/wp-content/themes/aloshop/7upframe/element`

file name: `product-tab.php`

child theme direction:

```
/public_html/wp-content/themes/aloshop-child/7upframe/element
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is there any chance you are calling the file with: get_template_directory_uri() cause this will alwayd lead to the parent theme.

Comment: at really I don't know how to call that file what I need but in the forums, I saw that this function get_template_directory_uri() not recommended using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your child theme style sheet is working then you have created the child theme properly. Still reminding you to check the name of parent name included in child theme style.css as 'Template : '

For overwriting the functions you have to copy the php file/functions from parent theme in the same hierarchy or by keeping the same folder file structure.

If your function is still working from parent theme just check from where your function is getting called. It may be from any other file from parent theme which is not included in child theme. In such case, include that file too to he child theme.

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Maybe there is any function that can write in the functions.php and it will use information that I put in the child theme

Comment: This is the method which i am following and in this way you can easily update your parent theme when new version comes in, without effecting the child theme or website, which is really very important for a secure website.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using child theme to modify your parent theme {aloshop} then use `get_stylesheet_directory()` function to get the child theme directory. and then call your other files via functions.php file . To include `product-tab.php` file via `functions.php` then put below codes into your child theme's **functions.php** file,

```
<?php include_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/product-tab.php'); ?>
```